# Run complex command from nodejs

Tags: node.js, shell

How would you run something like this for example,

```
diff 'README.md' <(ssh srcspider@localhost 'cat ~/example/README.md')
```

Comment: Would you put some research effort? There SSH and diff libraries for Node and it can read from a file. Would you like the code to be written for you?

Comment: @Pavlo I do not care so much for this particular case; it's just an example case. I have encountered similar cases in the past and resorted to libraries. I do not wish to have to resort to very convoluted libraries over libraries for something so common that *should* work if just sent to the terminal. My question is how can you invoke this easily. For reference methods like doing child_process.spawn will choke on it.